# Match string from table in order to update db

Tags: java, regex, arrays, string, compare

I have some JSON objects from which I retrieve the location for a Twitter user. This location is a text that may be relevant to what I need, e.g. "London", but it may also be a text like "The most awesome area ever!". So, what I need is to filter these texts (locations) so that they correspond to a UK city. UK has 69 cities, so I can make an array of them, using Java, and check with a regex whether the string I get from location matches or is close to one of the listed cities.

My question is: do you think there is a more efficient way for doing this? I think that going through a table of 69 strings again and again (imagine for 120.000 JSON objects) and comparing the mentioned strings will take ages. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Use this **Regex on your JSON reply...**

`[(city_name1)(city_name2)]`      **// do this till 69, then always use this pattern against the json reply you get, to fetch the matched city...**